# Git saying no changes when trying to merge

Tags: git, github

**master branch commits:**
*git log output*
removedc1Changes(latest commit)
c2
c1

Now I created a new branch named staging from master using c1 commit hash: *git checkout c1*

**staging branch commits :**
*git log output*
c1

Now if I try to merge staging branch to master, it says no changes..

I know it must be because same commit exists in both branches but in the master branch, it has been reverted..

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I want to get my C1 commit back in master that I have removed. I know I can do a git revert on master only but trying to figure out if I can do it this way.I want to continue using staging branch.

Comment: So in master you have C1 and C1 reverted, now you want to "revert" the reverted commit, is that right?

Comment: In order for both master and staging branch to both have c1, and staging seems to be *at* c1, it means that staging is along the same commit history that master is. If you want to merge staging into master, staging already *is* on master, so there's nothing to do. You're looking for the `revert` command, not `merge`. Use `git revert HASH-OF-REMOVEDC1CHANGES` to revert the removal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is this:

```
                        master
                           v
*---*---*---*---c1---c2---c1r
                ^
             staging
```

If you want to merge staging into master, git is correct in telling you there is nothing to do.

Everything on staging, this:

```
*---*---*---*---c1
                ^
             staging
```

is already on master, here:

```
+---- here ------+       master
|                |         v
*---*---*---*---c1---c2---c1r
```

what you need to do instead is to revert the removal of c1, this command:

```
git revert c1r
```

*(c1r = hash of the commit you call "removedc1Changes")*

This will give you this:

```
                              master
                                 v
*---*---*---*---c1---c2---c1r---c1rr
                ^
             staging
```

and in this scenario, you will again see the changes introduced by c1.

You don't need the staging branch.

A different approach would be to reset master to before the removal of c1, like this:

```
git reset --hard c2
```

This would give you this:

```
                   master
                     v
*---*---*---*---c1---c2
                ^
             staging
```

If your scenario is 100% accurate, the commit at the tip of master is the removal of the changes from c1, I would do the reset. If you have other commits after it, I would instead do the revert.

---

The reason why git merge doesn't do anything is that git doesn't try to merge state, it merges changes. Since no changes was done on staging that also wasn't already on master, there were no changes to merge, hence nothing to do.

Comment: Thanks Lasse for your explanation. Just one doubt, suppose that staging branch doesn't exist and i push my master branch on git server.Again master will have same commits(c1,c2,removedC1)..What if in future requirement comes that i have to get c1 commits back.I can not directly push to master because of some policy so cant revert on master.Then again i will have to create a branch from master using "git checkout c1" command. But wont it land me in the same earlier situation when i will go to merge this branch back to master.

Comment: @Lasses : or in above case we have to make changes manually??

Comment: Check out removedC1 in a new branch, revert it on that new branch, then make the pull request/merge back to master.

Answer (score 1):

"A thing is just the thing it is, and not some other thing." Git is what Git is, and not what you imagine Git to be or wish Git to be. To use Git, you need to know what Git is. A merge, in Git, is *a new commit that enacts all changes in both branches since the point of divergence.*

The point of divergence between your branches is `c1`. Since then, one branch has added `c2` and `removedc1Changes`. The other branch has added ... nothing.

Just as Git tells you, your `staging` branch has no changes on it since the point of divergence  (because you have made no new commits on the `staging` branch). Thus there is nothing to merge.

The only changes since `c1` are `c2` and `removedc1Changes` on `master`, and they are *already* on `master`. So there is nothing for a merge to do. The changes enacted by both branches since the point of divergence are already present on `master`. The only way to perform the merge would be for Git to create a new commit that is effectively empty, ie it is the same as `removedc1Changes`.

(Here's another way to look at it. It is true, as you say, that both branches contain `c1`. But since then, `master` has undone `c1`, and `staging` has done *nothing to contradict that*.)

Thus your pseudomerge is not a viable strategy for undoing the revert you did earlier. The way to undo a revert is to revert it, or to reset hard back to before the revert to erase it.

Comment: See my https://www.biteinteractive.com/understanding-git-merge/ for more.

Answer (score -1):

Judging by the discussion, you want to re-apply the C1 commit changes. I think you can use `git cherry-pick` of the C1 commit which will make a copy of the original commit, essentially re-applying it.

`git cherry-pick <C1 commit sha>`

You can do this on your staging branch before merging to master (or creating the PR).

Note this will keep the history as is and just add a new commit on top.